# Is this a correct example to show the benefit of the protocol-oriented design of the Swift?

Tags: swift, protocols

This question may be very wrong, and the result I would like to achieve may also very unclear. I'm a programming starter, please correct my wrong understandings. By your correction, I would learn a lot.

At 06:00 of the [Session 408](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g2LwFZatfTI) video of WWCD15, One of the three major Beefs of classes complained by Crusty is "Automatic Sharing!" The protocol-oriented characteristic of the swift can solve the problem nicely.

And here is the code I wrote for self-study

```
protocol pooPro {
    var a: Int { get }
    var b: Int { get }
    var c: Int { get }

}

extension pooPro {
    func pooFun() -> Int {
        return(a + b + c) //Function A
    }
}

struct bluePrint: pooPro {
    var a: Int
    var b: Int
    var c: Int

    func pooFun() -> Int {
        return(a * 10 + b * 10 + c * 10) // Function B
    }
}

let byBluePrint = bluePrint(a: 1, b: 2, c: 3)
print(byBluePrint.pooFun()) // #1 Use Function B

let byProtocol: pooPro = byBluePrint // #PassingValue
byProtocol.pooFun() //#2 Use Function A
```

The `byBluePrint` object of the type `bluePrint` invokes the **Function B** when `.pooFun()` has been called; The `byBluePrint` object of the type `byBluePrint` is assigned to `byProtocol` object of the type `pooPro`, but it doesn't bring the **Function B** to `byProtocol`, there fore the `byProtocol` object invokes the **Function A** when `.pooFun()` has been called

This is because the property or method that gets invoked is dependent on the context of the type declaration. This is amazing! (Part A)

**Question1:** What is the mechanism behind it (Described in Part A), how Swift did that? It may need some compiling knowledge and might be too much for a beginner, But I'm just curious and I want to know

**Question2:** Is the code shown here has something to do with the video I pointed out in the beginning? In another word, is this a correct example to show the Swift's protocol-oriented properties solved the "Automatic Sharing" problem in traditional OO

Thanks a lot for your kind help and time.

Comment: You may receive better answers on the [Code Review Stack Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @DanielStorm thanks for your infomation, I'll try it.

Comment: @Rob, Yes you are right, when I add `pooFun` as the protocol requirement,   `byBluePrint.pooFun()` and `byProtocol.pooFun()` would both return 60 then. Thanks a lot for your in deep discuss and help. Very good learning from you.

Comment: @DanielStorm as I see it this question would probably get closed on Code Review, because the code looks rather very hypothetical. For more information, see [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: @Rob Thanks a lot for your explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've shared an example where you cast an instance of a `struct` back to the protocol, when you call the method, it calls the protocol extension implementation rather than the `struct` implementation.

I personally wouldn't worry too much about the precise internal mechanisms Swift employs with this protocol extension, but rather I'd suggest you just note the behavior. But equally important, note that if the protocol declared `pooFun` to be part of the protocol requirements, then suddenly the behavior changes and the `struct` implementation is called even if you cast it back to the protocol type before calling the method.

Personally, I took this portion of the video as a cautionary note regarding some idiosyncratic behavior of protocol extensions rather than anything to be celebrated. I wouldn't want to write code dependent upon this particular feature as the intended behavior is not self-evident when reading the code.

> ... is this a correct example to show the Swift's protocol-oriented properties solved the "Automatic Sharing" problem in traditional OO

No, this is not good example of solving the "Automatic Sharing" problem. This sharing problem is solved through the use of value type.

The purpose of protocol extensions is merely to provide shared implementation and a customization point. In other words, it's showing how to implement an inheritable and/or overridable behavior while enjoying the benefits of value type.

Answer (score 0):

Your protocol definition itself looks fine.  You provide parameters the implementer must implement.

In the protocol extension, you are providing a default implementation of the `pooFun()` method.  Any class or struct that inherits your protocol gets the default implementation of `pooFun()` and you don't have to code a thing.  To test this you can remove the `pooFun()` method from your `bluePrint` struct and you will still be able to call it.

If you want to make sure the class/struct implements a function, but want the class to provide the specifics, you would define that in the protocol as:

```
func pooFun() -> Int
```

and then any class the implements your protocol would have to implement it.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. a very clear description ")